# iis error 500.19 ,the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: iis

After publishing the solution when i tried to access my home page im getting the following error.Its working localy in my system but when i tried to publish it im getting the following error.

[image]

Kindly reply as early as possible because im in a precaurious situation now